# How to work with date conditions using mongodb query operators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have a mongo db model with the name DrSlots. One of the fields in the model is slots which is as follows

```
      slots: [
          {
            slot: {
              start: {
                type: Date,
              },
              end: {
                type: Date,
              },
            },
            status: {
              type: String,
            },
          },
        ],
```

Now I want to find the slots based on certain conditions. Firstly the start time should be greater or equal to the start time provided by the user and the end time should be lesser or equal to the end time provided by the user in the same document. For this reason, I wrote the following query which for some reason is not executing correctly.

```
      const slots = await DrSlots.findOne({
          $and: [
            { doctor: req.params.doctorId },
            { dateOfAppointment: params.date },
            {
              "slots.slot": {
                start: { $gte: params.start },
                end: { $lte: params.end },
              },
            },
          ],
        });
```

I am not getting correct results.
Secondly I also want to implement that if params.start or params.end is not provided by user, the query should not check it. How would i implement this? TIA

Comment: Since `slots.slot` is an object with multiple sub keys, and you are trying to find elements that match both of those conditionals, you need to look at a usage of `$elemMatch`, which will return only elements that match *both* cases.  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: But I dont want to check two conditions for a single field. For start and end both I am just checking for a single value. How would elemMatch help here?

Comment: You are already checking two conditionals.  You are trying to find records that have a `slots.slot` that have a start property >= something, and an end property <= something.  That's two conditionals for each `slots.slot` object.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the slots between `start` and `end`, you could use `$elemMatch` and do the following:

```
$and: [
  ...,
  {
    slots: {
      $elemMatch: {
        start: { $gte: params.start },
        end: { $lte: params.end },
      }
    }
  }
]
```

As also pointed out by @Taplar in the comments.

Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: slots.slot right? Or should it be slots as you wrote above

Comment: No, no `"slots.slot"`. Those only work with `$ne` or `$not` ops.

Comment: Can you please tell how will I solve the second part. If params.start or params.end is not provided by user, the query should not check it. How would i implement this?

Comment: In that case, you could choose some min and max dates (e.g., min = 1970s, max = time now) depending on what you have. You should check if the params are provided or not, and if not, use the hardcoded min/max dates. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can make query using some condition basis.

let query = [
            { doctor: req.params.doctorId },
            { dateOfAppointment: params.date }
          ];

// and after that check params.start and params.end values
if (params.start && params.end) {
query.push({
    "slots.slot": {
      $elemMatch: {
        start: { $gte: params.start },
        end: { $lte: params.end },
      }
    }
  })
}

 const slots = await DrSlots.findOne({
          $and: query
        });
```